# How do I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli and SwaggerHostFactory to generate swagger.json correctly in .NET 6?

Tags: json, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli` and `SwaggerHostFactory` to generate **swagger.json**.

The generated **swagger.json** always empty for `path` and `compoments`, which is strange.

#### Create Project

```bash
dotnet new webapi -o DemoWebApi
cd DemoWebApi
dotnet restore
```

#### Example

- DemoWebApi.csrpoj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- create openapi cli -->
  <Target Name="OpenApiCliBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <!-- create static file openapi doc -->
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet new tool-manifest --force" />     
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool install --local Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli --version 6.4.0" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json $(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll v1" />     
  </Target>

</Project>
```

- C# Code

```cs
// SwaggerHostFactory.cs
public class SwaggerHostFactory
{
    public static IHost CreateHost()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        return app;
    }
}

// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ignore... same as SwaggerHostFactory
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

#### Run Project

```bash
dotnet watch run
```

#### Expected output

- If not using SwaggerHostFactory

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "DemoWebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/WeatherForecast": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "WeatherForecast"
        ],
        // ...ignore         
        }
      }
    }
  ,
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "WeatherForecast": {
        "type": "object",
        // ...ignore         
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Actual output

- Using SwaggerHostFactory

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "dotnet-swagger",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": { },
  "components": { }
}
```

Is `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli` support use `SwaggerHostFactory` int .NET 6? How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

In the end I gave up using `ASP.NET Core 6 top-level statements` and used the old style from `SwaggerHostFactory` and it worked fine.

But I think someone else may be have a better way.

```cs
public class SwaggerHostFactory
{
    public static IHost CreateHost()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(new string[0])
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(b => b.UseStartup<SwaggerStartup>())
            .Build();
    }

    private class SwaggerStartup
    {
        public SwaggerStartup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {}             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one solution (found here - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1580#issuecomment-1292223833), that helped me:

> To resolve this issue I had to set a value for application name, so finally my SwaggerHostFactory.CreateHost looks like that:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ApplicationName = typeof(SwaggerHostFactory).Namespace // without it, actions won't be added to swagger file
});
```

So, specifying ApplicationName might help, you can find more details following the link.